# jquery how to disable a td

Tags: jquery, html, disable

I have the following table

```
 <c:forEach items="${tablaserie.matriculas}" var="matricula" varStatus="loopmatricula">
    <input type="hidden" id="<c:out value="matricula-${loopmatricula.index}" />" value="<c:out value="${matricula.matricula}" />" />
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center"><c:out value="${matricula.matricula}" /></td>
        <c:set var="numeroceldas" value="${0}" />
        <c:forEach items="${matricula.listado}" var="celda" varStatus="loopcelda">
            <c:set var"identificadorcelda" value="${matricula.matricula}-${loopcelda.index}" />

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${celda.color eq '#ffffff' }" >       
                    <td  id="td-${identificadorcelda}" style="text-align:center;" onclick="displayCombo();" ><c:out value="${celda.nombre}" /></td>     
                    <input id="input-${identificadorcelda}" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${celda.nombre}" />" />              
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <td  id="td-${identificadorcelda}" style="color:white;text-align:center;" bgcolor="<c:out value="${celda.color}"/>"  onclick="displayCombo();">
                        <c:out value="${celda.nombre}" />
                    </td>
                    <input id="input-${identificadorcelda}" type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${celda.nombre}" />" />      

                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
    /c:forEach>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to disable the `td`. The names of `td` are

```
 id="td-${identificadorcelda}"
```

In the  `$(document).ready()`  I have

```
if (tipoedicion == 0){
            $("td[id*=td]").prop('disabled', true);

        }
        else {
            $("td[id*=td]").prop('disabled',false);
        }
```

The td don't disable and I can click in them.

How can I disable the td?

Comment: What would disabling a `td` accomplish, exactly? The `td` element doesn't have a `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent `onclick="displayCombo();` from executing?

Comment: As an aside, `value="<c:out value="${celda.nombre}" />"` looks weird. Wouldn't `value="${celda.nombre}"` work as well?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent the onclick

Comment: Then you could set a custom attribute on the `td` (like `data-disabled`) instead and check for that in the `displayCombo` function.

Comment: Could you explain me how to set the custom attribute data-disabled?

Comment: `$("td[id*=td]").attr('data-disabled', 'true');` should do the trick. To check it `$("td[id*=td]").attr('data-disabled') === 'true'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `td` doesn't really have a `disabled` attribute, if you want to prevent the `click` event from doing what it does, you could set a custom `data-disabled` attribute to your `td`s instead.

So in your `$(document).ready()` you can do something like this

```
if (tipoedicion == 0){
        $("td[id*=td]").attr('data-disabled', 'true');

    } else {
        $("td[id*=td]").attr('data-disabled', 'false');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then, in your `displayCombo()` function you can check that attribute and just return if the `td` has that attribute set to `"true"`, like this

```
function displayCombo() {
    if ($("td[id*=td]").attr('data-disabled') === 'true') {
        return;
    }
    // whatever it was doing before
}
```

Answer (score 2):

td does not have the disabled attribute. It is used for input elements. You can hide the mouse cursor on the td and disable selection. It will make it work like disabled

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a").prop("disabled", true);
  $('#b').css({
    'cursor': 'none',
    'user-select': 'none'
  });
  $('#b').click(function(){return false})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="b">sss</td>
</table>
<input id="a">
```